# Idiomatic way to cache computed values based on the state in React?

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

React documentation says

> Don't worry about precomputing values based on state — it's easier to ensure that your UI is consistent if you do all computation within render().

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

This makes perfectly sense when the computations are small.

But I'm storing the bunch of large arrays in `this.state` for data visualizations I'm rendering on SVG. I have to compute several values based on those. The thing is that those computations are fairly heavy and it is impossible to compute those always within render.

So, how should I go about caching those computations while ensuring that I don't get inconsistent state with `this.state` and those computed variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

I moved the large arrays to the state of the parent component and I'll just pass them as props to the visualization component. Then I just compute the values in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` and save them into the state of the visualization component.

This avoids most of the useless computing in my case. But if it is not enough I can go further and diff the current props with the next props in `componentWillReceiveProps` to determine if the computation is actually needed.

UPDATE: Now that I've worked more with React I think this should be done using memoizing. [Reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) is good lib for that.

Comment: It's kind of beautiful how React forces you into this kind of mental pattern of software design. Avoid maintaining state as much as possible, pushing "controlling" responsibilities up as high as possible in the component hierarchy. This allows for easier caching, less logic-heavy sub-components, and easier testing. I guess the danger lies in having a ueber parent component which acts as a god-controller, but that can be further reduced through other injection patterns.

Comment: Would it make more sense to compute in `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount`? Seems like the latter might force a second render.

Comment: @Bernardo could you please provide an example for those injection patterns? ATM. I am also developing an app which is generating an svg graphic, many values have to be calculated on the highest component level to correctly render the graphic. Reselect does not provide the comfort you would have with computed values in Ember.js

Answer (score 0):

I tried some data visualization with React and SVG as well, and did not have any performance problem yet. React only rerender on state change, or parent component's state change so those computations are not run very often.

If in your case the components are updating frequently, you can try memoize the computing functions with `lodash`.